# Trying to ouput exceptions to a file - how can I pass objects into catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, jxl

I've got a situation where I'm trying to process a load of rows in a table, and output the result (either success or an exception) to an excel spreadsheet using jxl. The problem is I can't see how to pass the initiated Excel workbook to the catch blocks so that the exception can be printed to it.
Below is some simplified code outlining the structure of my program (ignore any basic errors, I've just typed it up for demonstration purposes):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try{
     WritableWorkbook exceptionWB=Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("filename.xls");
     WritableSheet excepSheet=exceptionWB.createSheet("Exceptions",0);
     int exceptionRow=1;

     for(int i=0; i<numberOfRecords;i++){
          processRow(argument1, argument2, excepSheet, exceptionRow);
          }
   catch (Exception e){
          Label exception1=new Label(0, exceptionRow, e.getMessage());
          exceptionWB.write();
    }
}

public void processRow(String arg1, String arg2, WritableSheet sheet, int row){
    try{
      // A load of operations here
    } catch(Exception e) {
          Label exception1=new Label(0, exceptionRow, e.getMessage());
          exceptionWB.write();
    }
}
```

I get that the catch block does not have access to the sheet because it's not in scope, but if I move the Workbook initiation out of the try block it comes back with an error because there's no exception handling around it.

Is there a way of passing this WorkBook/Sheet around the various catch blocks, or should I be looking at an entirely different solution altogether?

Thanks

Comment: check out my answer you can define it without initializing it you can then initialize it within your `try` block which will still allow you access in your catch block...but be warned the object could be null at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WritableWorkbook exceptionWB = null;
    try{
        exceptionWB = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("filename.xls");
        WritableSheet excepSheet=exceptionWB.createSheet("Exceptions",0);
        int exceptionRow=1;

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfRecords;i++) {
            processRow(argument1, argument2, excepSheet, exceptionRow);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //You should now have access to the exceptionWB
            Label exception1=new Label(0, exceptionRow, e.getMessage());
            exceptionWB.write();
        }
}
```